# Speed discrepency when running tests via NPM vs IntelliJ

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, jestjs

This is more of a curiosity, really, but thought it might pique someone's interest and it would be good to know the answer...

We have a TypeScript application (built using CRA 2.1.8) which currently has approx. 2000 tests implemented using Jest (v23.3.8). When running them in IntelliJ, the full suite completes consistently in under 30 seconds.

When running the same tests in a terminal using `npm test`, it takes around 100s. The same is true in our CI pipeline.

Having run `ps` in CI I can see that the tests *are* being parallelised (I can see about 8 `/.../node_modules/jest-worker/build/child.js` processes running), so I don't think it's to do with that. Experimenting with `--runInBand` and `--maxWorkers` locally appears to make no difference to the total time elapsed.

Is IntelliJ just magic? What's it doing to get through the tests so fast, and can I implement it in CI? If anything, I would've thought there'd be *more* overhead in the IDE due to its pretty displays etc...

Have included our IntelliJ config for reference, which also shows the version of node that we're running.

[image: IntelliJ config]

Comment: You can run the same command line as IntelliJ runs and see if it's really faster.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the difference between IDE and terminal. Is there an open-source project that confirms the difference in run times for you?

Comment: Interestingly, I get a big speed boost simply by doing `export CI=true` before running `npm test` in my terminal. So I guess our local slowness is around the tests running in 'watch mode', which IntelliJ also won't be doing...

Comment: I'd recommend to take a look at recent Jest performance issues: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+watch+performance+